# When do rucksacks start disappearing?

Tags: state-of-decay

I have noticed that after a dozen or so rucksacks that I load and dump on the ground, old ones start disappearing. Does anyone know for sure if this is determined by time, the number of rucksacks on the map or any other factors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this discussion](http://stateofdecay.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:9515) on the SoD Wikia, the limit seems to be 10 rucksacks at any one time, anywhere on the map (including both resources and stuff left behind by a dead survivor).

Answer (score -1):

If there are a certain amount of rucksacks "looted" but not turned in, they do eventually disappear.

I've heard of hard limits like 8 or 10, they stay while they're in sight but get far enough away from them (like if you don't want to have a juggernaut hanging around your base, drive away from it a ways then come back and it's gone) the same distance applies to rucksacks on the ground/in vehicles.

In short, there is no way to stockpile looted rucksacks without extra storage or keeping it to a few at a time.

Also, they disappear a few at a time, not all at once, drives me crazy i once loaded up a pickup with 6 cases of materials, because I was currently maxed and wanted to save them for when i got to snyders.

anyway long story short got to snyders and went back to get the pickup and it had only 2 rucksacks in storage.

I think it's time based too, because i didn't go over the hard limit (or even close really, it was exactly 6 sacks).
have tested this same thing and basically, ANY rucksack you don't turn in eventually disappears. one or two takes longer to go away but they still will.

It's a damned if you do damned if you don't situation, leave them in the houses and some enclave will just come "claim" it an it's gone forever, conversely loot them and try to stash them, you run the risk of them being deleted.

I feel, stuff stored in vehicles should stay regardless. The only thing you can do is to drive the vehicle holding the rucksacks around EVERYWHERE and never get too far away from it. and then just hope you don't fine some resources you actually DO want to store in the car to take home, because you won't have space.